Showing $\sum_{y \in Y} f(x_0, y) = \sum_{(x,y) \in \{x_0\} \times Y} f(x, y)$.
Let $X, Y$ be finite sets, and let $f: X \times Y \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function. I am trying to show that
$$
\sum_{y \in Y} f(x_0, y) = \sum_{(x,y) \in \{x_0\} \times Y} f(x, y) 
$$
by using the following result $(1)$:

If $X$ is a finite set, $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function, and $g : Y \to X$ is a bijection, then
$$
\sum_{x \in X} f(x) = \sum_{y \in Y} f(g(y)) 
$$


To do this, I first consider $f$ to be restricted to $\{x_0\} \times Y$ (am I allowed to do this?). Letting $Z = \{x_0\} \times Y$, we see that $Z$ and $Y$ share the same cardinality. Therefore, there exists a bijection $g: Y \to Z$ such that for every $(x, y) \in Z$, there is a unique $y \in Y$ such that $g(y) = (x, y)$. Thus, by $(1)$,
$$
\sum_{(x,y) \in \{x_0\} \times Y} f(x, y) = \sum_{y \in Y} f(g(y)) \tag{2}
$$
But observe that for any $y \in Y$, $(x,y) \in Z$ is equal to $(x_0, y)$ by definition of $Z$. Thus, $g(y) = (x_0, y)$, implying by $(2)$,
$$
\sum_{(x,y) \in \{x_0\} \times Y} f(x, y) = \sum_{y \in Y} f(x_0, y) 
$$
as was to be shown.

Have I done this correctly? Is the answer to my question in bold above "Yes"?

Hi, may I miss something, but isn't it just $\sum_{(x,y) \in {x_0} \times Y} = \sum_{x=x_0, y \in Y} $ and so your result ? I mean, is it a constrain as exercise you want to do ? Anyway it is correct.

@EDX Hello! Yes, I'm constraining myself to only using the highlighted result $(1)$. Thanks for your input.

If that "yes" is yes to @EDX's comment why do we need a proof? $\sum\limits_{(x,y) \in {x_0} \times Y} f(x, y)$ is just a more clumsy way of writing $\sum\limits_{y \in Y} f(x_0, y),.$

@KurtG. Sorry, I think I wasn't clear. In order to show they're equal, I cannot simply use the equality EDX has stated. I need to explicitly make a substitution using some sort of bijection.

What are your doubts that $Y$ and ${x_0}\times Y$ might not have some sort of a bijection? Hint: they are finite and have the same cardinality.

@KurtG. I have no such doubts. You could see in my proof that I showed the existence of a bijection. I am more concerned of whether I used it correctly or not.

Hearing you having such concerns is irritating. If anything I would use a less confusing notation and write (1) as: If $A$ is a finite set, and $f:A \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function, and $g:Y \to A$ is a bijection, then
$$
\sum_{a \in A} f(a) = \sum_{y \in Y} f(g(y)),.
$$
To use this set $A={x_0}\times Y$  and the bijection (as dou did): $g(y):=(x_0,y),.$

@KurtG. thank you, Kurt. I’m self-studying this material; sometimes I get to a point where I don’t trust my steps unfortunately, and need a second eye to look at them.

Yes, the restriction of $f$ to $\{x_0\} \times Y$ is allowed. The justification is that the restriction is well-defined since $f$ is well-defined too.
As for the existence of the bijection, since you're working with finite sets, you could explicitly define the bijection by enumerating the elements, otherwise it is quite easy for most readers to see why there is a bijection.
